# Not able to open file using fstream

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, fstream

I think I may not have the file I'm trying to read in the right spot but i've put it everywhere possible in the IDE and it is still not working. Ive even put it next to the .exe for my program and it still cant find it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tE1KI.jpg)

I was expecting the file to be able to be opened so I can read its contents with c++ code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>       
#include <cstdlib>  // exit prototype
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ifstream inFile;
    string filename = "infile6";
    // if a filename is provided, open file
    cout << "Enter the name of a file to read from: " << endl;
    //cin >> filename;
    cout << "Name of a file requested: " << filename << endl;

    inFile.open(filename.c_str());
    if (!inFile)
    {
        cerr << endl;
        cerr << "File cannot be opened" << " " << filename << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    return 0;  // ifstream destructor closes file

} // end main
```

Comment: yeah I know I dont have an "infile1" file but the same "File cannot be opened" happends with "infile2".

Comment: Write a small "Hello World" that writes to a file.  Run it.  Now find the file.  This is the default location, if you don't specify a path (or it's the starting location for a relative path).

Comment: You are trying to open the file using a *relative* path. Chances are, the program's **current working directory** is not referring where you think it is at runtime. Always open files using *absolute* paths instead, for exactly this reason. You can use `std::file_system::current_path()` or equivalent to see where the CWD is actually pointing.

Comment: The creating a file helped me locate where I should place the files i was trying to read. The file now opens. Thank you! Also, or my assignment we are required to use a relative path so that his software can run the program.

Comment: Since C++11 you can create `inFile` from `std::string` without converting name to C-style string: `std::ifstream inFile(filename)`

Answer (score 1):

The default location of projects created with Visual Studio is:

`C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Documents\Visual Studio 2022\Projects`

> replace `Visual Studio 2022` with your version

Your binary file is located deep inside that directory tree

> Most likely :
>
> `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Documents\Visual Studio 2022\Projects\RA2\Debug\RA2.exe`
> or
> `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Documents\Visual Studio 2022\Projects\RA2\Debug\RA2.exe`

```
RA2/
    ├── RA2.sln
    ├── RA2.vcxproj
    ├── RA2.vcxproj.filters
    ├── Debug/
    │   └── RA2.exe
    ├── Source Files/
    │   └── main.cpp
    ├── Header Files/
    │   └── ...
    ├── Resource Files/
    │   └── ...
    └── ...
```

Now, your program is expecting the file `infile6` to be located in the same
directory as your executable(`C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Documents\Visual Studio 2022\Projects\RA2\Debug\`).

You can either copy/paste your file in that directory, or you can provide the absolute path to your `infile6`.

> Here is the absolute path ssuming your username is `Bob` and Visual Studio version `2022`

`string filename = "C:\\Users\\Bob\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2022\\Projects\\RA2\\Source Files\\infile6";`

> P.S if you use C++17 you should take advantage of std::filesystem to deal with file paths, its cleaner, safer, and the modern way.